# Performance issue in calling Array's inherited method (push)

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototypal-inheritance

I am trying to create a Stack constructor by inheriting the properties and methods of built in Array constructor. Something like this -

```
var Stack = function(){};

Stack.prototype = [];
Stack.prototype.constructor = Stack;
```

Then I tried to check the performance in terms of milliseconds in case of pushing 1000000 data in an array and same number of data in the newly created Stack constructor.

Below is the result for the test -

> "Time taken in ms in Array -> 11"
>
> "Time taken in ms in Stack -> 261"

I do understand, push method need to be looked up in the prototype chain, but still the difference is huge. Is there anything which can be done to improve the performance?

I have also tried adding a push method to the Stack constructor, but it has almost no effect in the performance improvement.

```
Stack.prototype.push = function(data){
    Array.prototype.push.call(this, data);
}
```

I have created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/linux_nerd/du57jzks/) for the same issue.

Comment: @Cerbrus The Fiddle contains the test as well.

Comment: It's quite simple: [you cannot subclass arrays](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/). Your `Stack` instances will be plain objects, and not be optimised for array access.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for Sharing the link.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know the exact reason, but defining the `Stack` in such a way makes a huge difference. but I am assuming it is taking so much time in Binding the `push` method with the `this` object.

```
var Stack = function(){
    this.arr = [];
    this.push = function(elem) {
        this.arr.push(elem);
    }
};
```

**Output Snippet**

[image: Output Snippet]

Still digging out on this question, will come with an update, soon.